# Let $f_n,g_1,g_2$ be such that for some $r_1,r_2>0$, $\int |f_n-g_1|^{r_1}\to 0$ and $\int |f_n-g_2|^{r_2}\to 0$. Is it true that $g_1=g_2$ ae?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f_n,g_1,g_2$ be such that for some $r_1,r_2>0$, $\int |f_n-g_1|^{r_1}\to 0$ and $\int |f_n-g_2|^{r_2}\to 0$. Is it true that $g_1=g_2$ ae?

I think the answer should be yes. Here's my argument: Let $E=\{x: g_1(x)\neq g_2(x)\}$. Let us assume that $\mu(E)>0$. Then there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that the measure of the set $\{x:|g_1(x)-g_2(x)|>\epsilon\}$ is greater than $0$. Let this set be $E'$, and let $\mu(E')=\delta$.

**Part 1**: As $\int |f_n-g_1|^{r_1}\to 0$, by Chebyshev inequality, the measure of the set $\{x:|f_n-g_1(x)|>\epsilon/3\}\leq \frac{3}{\epsilon} \int |f_n-g_1|^{r_1}$. For some $N\in\Bbb{N}$, if $m\geq N$, then $\frac{3}{\epsilon} \int |f_n-g_1|^{r_1}< \frac{\delta}{4}$. Hence, $\{x: |f_n(x)-g_1(x)|>\epsilon/3\}<\frac{\delta}{4}$.

**Part 2**: Similarly, as $\int |f_n-g_2|^{r_2}\to 0$, there exists $N'\in\Bbb{N}$ such that for $m\geq N'$, we have $\{x:|f_m-g_2(x)|>\epsilon/3\}<\frac{\delta}{4}$.

Let us now focus on $E'$ again. This is the set of points such that $|g_1(x)-g_2(x)|>\epsilon$. Also, $\mu(E')=\delta$. However, for at least a $\frac{3\delta}{4}$ subset of $E'$, $f_n(x)$ should stay within an $\epsilon/3$ neighborhood of $g_1(x)$, and the same goes goes for $g_2(x)$. We get this from Parts 1 and 2 respectively. Hence, at least for a $\delta/2$ subset of $E'$, $f_n(x)$ must be within both the $\epsilon/3$ neighborhood of $g_1$, and the $\epsilon/3$ neighborhood of $g_2$. This is impossible, as the $2$ neighborhoods are disjoint.

Is this argument correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read your proof, but it looks very complicate for such an easy proof.

If $f_n\to g_1$ in $L^{r_1}(\mathbb R)$, there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$ that converge a.e. to $g_1$. Same, since $f_n\to g_2$ in $L^{r_2}(\mathbb R)$, then so is $(f_{n_k})_k$. And thus, there is a subsequence $(f_{n_{k_j}})_j$ that converge a.e. to $g_2$. Finally, we get $g_1=g_2$ a.e.

Comment: Just confirming. For this to be true, it is not required that $r_1,r_2\geq 1$? I don't think it is, but just confirming

Comment: @fierydemon, Convergence in measure is enough to extract an a.e.-convergent subsequence, and by the Markov's inequality, $L^r$-convergence for $r > 0$ implies convergence in measure.

Comment: Actually I don't think this proof works. The two subsequences that converge point wise to $g_1$ and $g_2$ might be completely disjoint. Hence, we don't get that $g_1=g_2$.

Comment: @fierydemon : You should read more carefully my proof. The subsequence of $(f_n)$ that converge to $g_2$ is not an unspecified subsequence of $(f_n)$ and depend on the subsequence of $(f_n)$ that converge to $g_1$. So the case you are talking about doesn't hold.

Comment: Ah yes you're right. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome :-)